# Celery with redis: instance state changed (master -> replica?)

Tags: docker, redis, celery

Am using celery for scheduled tasks and redis server for data backup within docker containers. My jobs are running correctly sometimes. But I am get following error randomly and celery beat task can no longer progress.

```
[2020-09-16 21:01:07,863: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ResponseError('UNBLOCKED force unblock from blocking operation, instance sta
te changed (master -> replica?)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 205, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 599, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 83, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 364, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1088, in on_readable
    self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 359, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 739, in _brpop_read
    **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 892, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 752, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: UNBLOCKED force unblock from blocking operation, instance state changed (master -> replica?)
```

Any help is will be appreciated. Let me know in case you need more details

Comment: Maybe worth checking whether it is a redis-py issue: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I stated above the issue is happening randomly and perturb our app in production. So I decided to spend time on a solution. I came across many propositions such as hardware issues (Memory or CPU). But [this one](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/6420) definitively solve the issue. **I was not using authentication on redis server** Those interesting on setting redis password easily in docker can refer to this [Docker Tip](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-27-setting-a-password-on-redis-without-a-custom-config). After setting a password to redis the url looks like `REDIS_URL=redis://user:myPass@localhost:6379`

Comment: ok... but what about the user?
I mean, if I specify `command: redis-server --requirepass yourpassword` in my docker-compose, which user I can use in the connection string? I tried googling around but without success. Thanks

Comment: If you did not set any user. Try `default`

Comment: @Rumakama yes finally worked even using `redis://:myPass@localhost:6379` as documented thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Instead of password protecting Redis, I removed its docker-compose port mapping as I wasn't using it outside the docker network.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74141982/1635525

TLDR Adding `restart: unless-stopped` to your docker-compose helps to recover from celery crashes including the ones caused by redis downtime/maintenance.