# Celery worker state changes to offline after a while, how to process it?

Tags: python, redis, celery, worker, flower

After several hours running, worker appear as offline in flower.
[image]

This is what the container shows
[image]

Solution:

I solved my problem by setting a password on Redis.
[this worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240828/celery-with-redis-instance-state-changed-master-replica)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is obvious. The underlined log output is not important, what is important is the error that was logged before - the `You can't write against a read only replica`. Looks like your result backend (Redis) is read-only, so Celery can't write results there.

You have two options here:

1. Modify the Redis server to run in read-write state.
2. Change the result backend to something else.