# Celery crash with redis.exceptions.ResponseError: UNBLOCKED

Tags: python, django, docker, redis, celery

I am using **Celery** with **Django** and **Redis** for everyday tasks. It works actually, but sometimes celery crashes with `redis.exceptions.ResponseError`, which i can't allow. I saw [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64318785/22401692) with configuring redis authentication, but it didn't work for me (or i did something wrong).

###### celery auth log

```
[2024-01-24 08:49:17,548: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://default:**@redis:6379/0
```

###### error

```
[2024-01-24 08:51:10,365: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ResponseError('UNBLOCKED force unblock from blocking operation, instance state changed (master -> replica?)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 202, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 365, in start
    return self.obj.start()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 340, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 742, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 97, in asynloop
    next(loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/hub.py", line 373, in create_loop
    cb(*cbargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 1344, in on_readable
    self.cycle.on_readable(fileno)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 569, in on_readable
    chan.handlers[type]()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/transport/redis.py", line 962, in _brpop_read
    dest__item = self.client.parse_response(self.client.connection,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 553, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 524, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: UNBLOCKED force unblock from blocking operation, instance state changed (master -> replica?)
```

###### docker-compose

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  django:
    image: django-service
    container_name: django
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file:
      - .django
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: /django-start.sh

  celery:
    image: django-service
    container_name: celery
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .django
    depends_on:
      - django
    command: /celery-start.sh

  celery-beat:
    image: django-service
    container_name: celery-beat
    restart: on-failure
    env_file:
      - .django
    depends_on:
      - django
    command: /celery-beat-start.sh
```

###### redis.conf

```
requirepass someInsanePass
```

###### celery-start.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

celery -A celery_worker.app worker --loglevel=debug -E --uid=nobody --gid=nogroup
```

###### celery-beat-start.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

celery -A celery_worker.app beat --loglevel=debug
```

###### Django settings

```py
...
# CELERY
# --------------------------------------------------
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", "redis://default:someInsanePass@localhost:6379/0")
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", "redis://default:someInsanePass@localhost:6379/0")
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "some_everyday_task_1": {
        "task": "apps.app1.tasks.task1",
        "schedule": crontab(hour=0, minute=0),
    },
    "some_everyday_task_2": {
        "task": "apps.app2.tasks.task2",
        "schedule": crontab(hour=4, minute=0),
    },
}
...
```

###### .django

```
# ...
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://default:someInsanePass@redis:6379/0
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://default:someInsanePass@redis:6379/0
# ...
```

###### celery_worker.app

```py
from celery import Celery, Task

app = Celery("tasks")

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')


class BaseTask(Task):
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        raise exc
```

Comment: Have you tried to use redis without password protection? Does it work then?

Comment: @KhanAsfiReza It worked exactly the same. I've added a password as one of the suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this issue on github](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/6420) where itamarhaber said:

> I'm taking a wild guess here - your Redis server isn't password protected and is open to the public. If this is the case, a nefarious entity is attempting to hijack the server via the `SLAVEOF` command.

In my case, setting password for redis wasn't the solution. But **closing ports for Redis** was.

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```